# Prove the logarithm of the energy function of the $n$d heat equation is convex.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Given the problem $$u_t-\Delta u=0$$ in $D \times (0,T)$
$$u=0$$ in $\partial D \times [0,T]$
$$u=g$$ in $ D \times \{t=0\}$
Where $D$ is some open and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $T>0$, $\partial D$ is $C^1$ and $u$ is $C^2$.

Given the energy $$E(t)=\int_{D} u^2 (r,t) dr$$
Prove that $h(t)=\ln E$ is convex.

My attempt is the following, I take the second derivative of $h$ to get $$h''=\frac{E''E-(E')^2 }{E^2}$$

Then take the derivative of the energy to get $$E'(t)=2\int_D u u_t dr$$ since $u_t=\Delta u$ I get $$E'(t)=2\int_D u \Delta u dr$$ and after using Green's identity I get $$E'(t)=2\int_{\partial D} u \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} -2\int_{D} | \nabla u |^2 dr $$
since $u=0$ on the boundary the I am left with $$E'(t)=-2\int_{D} | \nabla u |^2 dr $$

Now if I take the second derivative I get $$E''(t)=-4\int_D \nabla u \nabla u_t dr $$
Using Green's identity I get $$E''=-4\int_{\partial D} u_t \frac{\partial u }{\partial n}+4\int_D u_t \Delta u dr$$
now since $u=0$ on the boundary then $u_t=0$ on the boundary and I am left with $$E''(t)=4
\int_D u_t \Delta u dr$$
Since $\Delta u=u_t$
I get $$E''(t)=4
\int_D u_t^2 dr$$
If I plug those in $h''$ I get $$h''(t)=\frac{4\int_D \int_D u_t^2(r,t) u^2 (r',t) drdr'-(E')^2 }{E^2} $$
$E^2$ and $(E') $ are always non-negative, but this doesn't give me anything useful.

For a function to be convex, it's second derivative must be non-negative and here for $h''$ I can't see how this is true, can you help?

Comment: Thank you for taking the effort to write a very neat question, +1 and wish you get plenty of attention.

Comment: Take a look at the notes at (first result when you search "lecture 7 heat equation and energy uci sites", can't paste it here because it's an awful long link), step 3 of the Backwards Uniqueness proof. You seem to only be missing integration by parts in $E'$, Cauchy-Schwarz and changing $u_t$ by $\Delta u$ in $E''$.

Comment: You can try to match the argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262946/uniqueness-for-3-dimensional-heat-equation-initial-robin-boundary-value-problem?rq=1). See the last step, in particular.