# Uniqueness of the heat equation with robin boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation, maximum-principle

I am trying to show uniqueness of solutions for the homogeneous heat equation with unhomogeneous Robin Boundary Conditions, i.e.

$$
u_t(x,t) = u_{xx}(x,t), \quad x>0, t>0
$$
$$
u(x,0) = 0, \quad x>0,
$$
$$
u_x(0,t) + \alpha u(0,t) = f(t), \quad t>0,
$$

with $\alpha < 0$.

I am aware that the Energy method and Maximum principle are usually used to prove uniqueness of this kind of problems but I was not able to find any proper reference for the maximum principle used in this specific case and I was not able to understand it the Energy method applied to this problem (see below).

I found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262946/uniqueness-for-3-dimensional-heat-equation-initial-robin-boundary-value-problem) that tackles this question using the Energy method, but I do not understand the concept of *logarithmic convexity* of the Energy.

I would also be very happy if someone could provide some reference of the Maximum principle applied to this specific problem